# I don't understand one line of code |Multitouch|

Tags: java, android, eclipse, location, multi-touch

```
  private void dealEvent(int actionPointerIndex, MotioEvent event,
  View eventView, int actionresolved) {

  int rawX, rawY;
  int location[] = { 0, 0 };


  eventView.getLocationOnScreen(location);
rawX = (int) event.getX(actionIndex) + location[0];
rawY = (int) event.getY(actionIndex) + location[1];

ArrayList<View> views = getTouchedViews(rawX, rawY, actionresolved);
```

I don't understand these line, why do we do that?

```
rawX = (int) event.getX(actionIndex) + location[0];
rawY = (int) event.getY(actionIndex) + location[1];

ArrayList<View> views = getTouchedViews(rawX, rawY, actionresolved);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly supposition since the code you provided isn't quite compilable (`MotioEvent` should be `MotionEvent` and you use `actionPointerIndex` in the function declaration and `actionIndex` in the body).

Based on [this link](http://www.passsy.de/multitouch-for-all-views/), one of the features is that the events are automatically forwarded to the underlying view.

It looks like the return values from `getX` and `getY` are relative to some non-origin point (for example, the upper left corner of the object which captured the event).

The `getLocationOnScreen` call populates `location` with that point and you then use that to generate raw (probably screen) co-ordinates from the relative ones.

Most likely, that's because `getTouchedViews` requires raw co-ordinates to give you a list of views at that point. The code then goes through that list to figure out which view should receive the event.

Comment: I understand it now, thank you very much ;)

BTW. just the fragment intrigued me;)